# ignoring duplicate libraries -lc++

Tags: ios, crashlytics, xcode15

I get this warning when build my iOS project on Xcode 15. Xcode 14 didn't get them.

```
FirebaseCrashlytics
Ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
```

Does anyone know if this warning Can/Should be fixed and How?

Answer (score 1):

This is a new warning added in Xcode 15. It is not critical and it is safe to be ignored. It seems they won't address it in Firebase Crashlytics anytime soon: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11818

Till then, you may suppress it by including this option in "Other Linker Flags" in your project settings:

```
-Xlinker -no_warn_duplicate_libraries
```